# visual 2015 shortcut search untiy API

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Referring to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7C7WWxUxPZE 4:48

Does Visual studio 2015 have a shortcut to search the unity API, and if so what is the shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard shortcut is:  <kbd>CTRL + ALT + M</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd>

If you want a simpler shortcut or even to make it the same as in MonoDevelop, you can do the following...

Open Visual Studio
Go to: Debug > Options and Settings > Environment > Keyboard
Find command "Help.UnityAPIReference"
Assign a new shortcut. Personally I am using <kbd>CTRL+ALT+'</kbd>
Original [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/842503/view.html)